# ¿Cómo llamar los datos de una base de datos y modificarlos?

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer un modifcador de una base de datos, que primero me muestre lo que existe y poder modificar eso.
Estoy ocupando esto:

```
 <?php
            $re = mysqli_query($con, "select * from notas where id=1") or die(mysqli_error($con));
            while ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($re)) {
            ?>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>Titulo: <span>*</span>
                        <textarea class="minresize" name="contenido" required><?php echo $f['titulo']; ?></textarea>
                    </label>
?>
```

¿Como puedo hacer que se guarde lo que modifique?

Este es mi php de actualizar:

```
<?php
    include ("../../conexion.php");
    if(!isset($_POST['titulo']) &&  !isset($_POST['resumen']) && !isset($_POST['contenido'])){
        header("Location: agregar.php");
    }else{
                    $titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
                    $resumen=$_POST['resumen'];
                    $contenido=$_POST['contenido'];
                    $imagen=$_POST['imagen'];
                    $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
                    $autor=$_POST['autor'];
                    $Sql="UPDATE `notas` SET `titulo`=$titulo,`resumen`=$resumen,`contenido`=$contenido,`imagen`=$imagen,`fecha`=$fecha,`autor`=$autor WHERE id=1";

                    
                    mysqli_query($con,$Sql);
                    header ("Location: modificar.php");
              }
?>
```

Comment: Para modificar algo **en la base de datos** tendrás que ejecutar una consulta del tipo `UPDATE`. MUY IMPORTANTE: No olvides poner un criterio (WHERE)  o un límite (LIMIT) o de lo contrario te cambiará todos los registros de la tabla.

Comment: Modifique la pregunta agregando el script de actualizar, si le puede echar un ojo lo agradecería, ya que no funciona

Comment: ¿Qué hace el código? ¿Da error, muestra algo, redirige a alguna parte? No estás depurando nada ni controlando nada en tu código. Usa var_dump para verificar el $_POST y controla las ejecuciones de las consultas.

Comment: Las variables post se están ejecutando de manera correcta, si coloco:
`echo $titulo, $resumen, $contenido,$imagen,$fecha,$autor; `
en lugar del  `header` me muestra los datos que yo puse, pero no los actualiza en la base de datos

Comment: Como ya dije antes, chequea la ejecución de tus consultas, por ejemplo: `if ( mysqli_query($con,$Sql) ) { echo "Filas actualizadas: ".mysqli_affected_rows($con); } else { echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($con);}`

Comment: Muchas Gracias!, el error radicaba en que estaba poniendo las variables `(`titulo`=$titulo )`  sin comillas y tomaba esa variable como referencia, al agregarle las comillas a las variables se soluciono el problema`(`titulo`='$titulo')`

Comment: Me alegro. De todos modos no deberías programar de forma ingenua, sin controlar los posibles errores y sin dar seguridad al código. Tu tarea como programador es pensar en todo aquello que pueda salir mal y salir al paso cuando eso ocurra, estableciendo un control de errores, como he hecho en mi anterior comentario. Eso deberías hacerlo con todo lo que pueda salir mal. Para funciones como `mysqli_error` úsala solamente para la fase de desarrollo, estableciendo una política de control de errores en la que evites mostrar mensajes de error internos. Por último, deberías usar consultas preparadas.

Comment: Agradezco el comentario y la ayuda, aun soy novato y día a día pretendo aprender de mis errores, tomare en cuenta los comentarios y consejos que se tomo la molestia de escribir, es un gran agrado que exista gente como usted, muchas gracias nuevamente.